# SwiftUI sidebar list bottom items not responding on click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Here I have Sidebar list in which I am having list of item coming from my modelview.
When I tap on top items are responding. But few bottom items(cells in swift) not respond on click and row that are not responding vary depending on device I am checking.
Let suppose I am having 12 items in my list upto 7 rows are working in iPhone 8 and for iPhone 11 pro upto 9 rows are working.

**SideMenuListView.swift**

Here is the code for listing menu on sidebar.

```
 List {
       ForEach(self.viewModel.data,id: \.id) { item in
                ZStack(alignment:.leading) {
                        SideMenuCell(image: Image(item.imageName), title: item.name)
                            .frame(height: 42)

                        NavigationLink.init(destination: item.view) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
}
```

Code for creating side menu:

**SideMenuContentView.swift**

```
          GeometryReader { _ in
              EmptyView()
          }
          .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
          .opacity(self.isOpen ? 1.0 : 0.0)
          .animation(Animation.easeIn.delay(0.25))
          .onTapGesture {
              // Close Menu on click outside menu.
              self.menuClose()
          }
          VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
              /// Set Profile View on top.
              SideMenuHeader().fixedSize()
                  .frame(width: self.width,height: 150)
                  .offset(x: self.isOpen ? 0 : -self.width)
                  .animation(.default)

              /// Set Sidemenu View.
              HStack {
                  SideMenuListView(viewModel: SideMenuListViewModel())
                      .frame(width: self.width)
                      .background(Color.white)
                      .offset(x: self.isOpen ? 0 : -self.width)
                      .animation(.default)
                      .onDisappear {
                          // close side menu
                          self.isOpen = false
                      }
                  Spacer()
              }
          }
      }
```

Is there something overlaying my cell? How can I debug that is there any overlay over my content.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test provided code, so just by code reading, I assume the issue is due to .offset

```
  SideMenuHeader().fixedSize()
      .frame(width: self.width,height: 150)
      .offset(x: self.isOpen ? 0 : -self.width)  // << here !!
      .animation(.default)

  /// Set Sidemenu View.
  HStack {
      SideMenuListView(viewModel: SideMenuListViewModel())
          .frame(width: self.width)
          .background(Color.white)
          .offset(x: self.isOpen ? 0 : -self.width) // << here !!
```

that's because `.offset` does not change layout/frame/contentArea of view, it shifts only visual representation rendered on screen, so real view is not at the place where user see it and try to interact.

Thus the solution is to remove those offsets and rethink layout.